# pyFlink submit job with multiple external connector jars on Amazon Kinesis

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink, amazon-kinesis-analytics

I am follwing [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/java/gs-python-createapp.html) to create an Amazon Kinesis Analytics Application with pyflink, and my application requires more than 1 external connector jarfile. When it comes to the jarfile uploading section, it seems I can only upload 1 jarfile, how can I upload multiple jarfiles?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/71271291/19921781